# Is reported speech reasonable in this example?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-perfect, indirect-speech

What is the right word to the gap (21)? (**had/have**)

> That is about 400 years earlier than when the Inca Indians were
>   thought to (21) **__** discovered the silver in the ground.

I think it's **had** as the tense before is past simple, but the official solution is **have**
Which one is the right anwser?

Answer (score 1):

*To have*. One should definitely use the infinitive. "He seemed *to walk* straight", "she was told *to listen* carefully".

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. Please support it with references (such as a link to a reputable source). Also check spelling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have is right. After to you cannot have a past tense word - here 'had'. To +verb is infinitive . All infinitives will have 'to' and the base verb. (which is always present tense. it is also called as root verb.